# Read from http protocol and put into string array (Android/Java)

Tags: java, android, arrays, http

My code reads from http connection and puts the data into an `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

The http data content has the first row with the update date/time and then the other data.

Example of data received from http url:

```
2012-03-02 03:06:34
text1
text2
text3
```

I have found this:

```
    InputStream content = response.getEntity().getContent();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int numRead = 0;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    while((numRead=content.read(buffer))!=-1){
        baos.write(buffer, 0, numRead);
    }
    content.close();
    String result = new String(baos.toByteArray());
```

How can I use the first row ("2012-03-02 03:06:34") and then the others row?

I'll think to use an array of strings and get the first row with baos[0] and the others with

```
for (int i=1;i<baos.length;i++) {...}
```

How I can?
Thanks.
my english is very ugly   :-o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have works more on a byte-at-a-time level.

Try this for a line at a time:

```
    InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        //Do something with each line
    }
```

Comment: Was just what I needed, a simple code to use.
Thanks very very much